# Why is transform rotate on hover not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm making circular buttons with multiple gradients, And it's suppose to rotate on hover..

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="home">Home</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.navigation li {
        float: left;
    }

.navigation li a {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.home {
    background: linear-gradient(130deg, #aac4df 15%, #556270 25%, #556270 50%, #414F55 50%);
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    line-height: 110px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.home:hover {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

I'm facing multiple problems here..

1- The rotation on .home:hover is not working, in any browser.

2- If it does work my guess it would rotate both the circular background and the text "Home". Would there be a way to rotate the circle only?

3- I'm not sure how to explain this one, But it's as if the circle doesn't have enough polygons, There is visible straight lines that could be seen when zooming, This problem appears only in some browsers and doesn't seem to change by setting the border-radius into something bigger.

Comment: pls create a fiddle script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your hover style to

```
 li:hover .home {
     background: linear-gradient(90deg, #aac4df 15%, #556270 25%, #556270 50%, #414F55 50%);
 }
```

will solve all your problems

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPhLd/)

Comment: Yeah! Thank you so much, That pretty much did what I wanted. But I still don't understand why rotation didn't work.

Comment: the transform rotate worked too on li:hover .home .. perfect, thanks again.